# How to separate Month and Year in one column to two columns in R

Tags: r

The format of my Year and Month column right now is '200101'. I retrieved data from EIA such as ELEC.GEN.COW-AL-99.M so it was a default like that. Is there any way to split it into two separate columns?

Comment: It would really help if you added more detail to your post. Consider reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If you want them just as strings, you can use `substr` to split the text into the first 4 characters and then the last two characters.

Once you have that you can convert them as you wish.

```
x="200506"
> substr(x,1,4)
[1] "2005"
> substr(x,5,6)
[1] "06"
```

If you want them as `datetime` objects, you can use lubridate, for example:

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time("200406","Ym")
```

Gives `"2004-06-01 UTC"`

See the [lubridate documentation](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_date_time.html) for more details.